# Are they connected in parallel?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

The question was to find the equivalent resistance between A and B. The correct answer is R. I too arrived at R by considering the ends of the lowest two wires equi-potent because the lowest wire has 0 resistance (and so according to V=IR, V comes out to be 0) and redrawing the circuit by taking the equi-potent points as a single point. But then when i was again inspecting the circuit, it seemed to me that the lowest two wires are connected in parallel which would make the equivalent resistance across their ends 0 since r1=rr'/(r+r') and thus the equivalent resistance between A and B comes out to be R/2. I think this is certainly not the case since the correct answer is R. So are the lowest two wires connected in parallel(which is probably not the case and if not then why?

Edit: I would like to know how to proceed if the bottom wire also has a resistor of resistance R. I am unable to simplify the circuit for this.

Comment: Yes they are but the resistance of the lowest wire is essentially 0.  Taking the parallel equivalent of the two lowest wire would be equivalent to the middle wire.

Comment: How?[r-eq=rr'/(r+r')]=>[r-eq=r*0/(r+0)]=>[r-eq=0]

Comment: try placing the bottom wire in the middle and "pulling" points A and B away from each other. From there it is obvious that the top and bottom will be R/2, and since two parts are in series, the total resistance will be R.

Comment: @Naz How do you know that they are in series?

Comment: Just re-draw it as I said. If you label the resistors clockwise, you will get R1 and R2 parallel to each other; the R3 and R4 will be parallel to each other. Both pairs are in series between A and B.

Comment: Yeah, just re-draw it.  Then it will make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two resistances are connected in parallel if their positives are connected together and negatives are connected together. In your problem here the first and third wire are connected in parallel as well as the 2nd and third wire as shown in this sketch.

[image: here]

Comment: The net resistance between the end points of the second and third wire should come out to be 0 and not R/2(the one which you are dot-circled).

Comment: @MrAP the net resistance between 2nd and 3rd wire is definitely zero but not between point b and third wire as mentioned in my answer

Comment: If the equivalent resistance between 2nd and 3rd wire is zero, then the equivalent resistance between a and b comes out to be be R/2.

Comment: @MrAP no that's not true you if you see the 2nd part of my diagram you will understand it better .you are trying to find equivalent resistance between point a and b not between the Ends of the first wire and point b .there is nothing to get so much confused

Comment: Ok. But how do you know that the resistors across B are connected in parallel?

Comment: @MrAP because two resistors are connected in parallel only if they originate from a common point and end up at a different common point.

Comment: They originate from a common point because the two points are equipotent. Right?

Comment: What do you think of my last comment @navinstudent?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct :)@MrAP

Comment: How would you proceed if the bottom wire also had a resistor of resistance R?

Comment: I am getting R as the equivalent resistance. I simplified the circuit using Wheatstone bridge principle.

Comment: The  answer will be $R/2$ then.you were correct to use the principle of Wheatstone bridge.just notice that you can change the position of galvanometer and the battery in such an arrangement.

Comment: How are you getting R/2? My answer is R.

Comment: @MrAP please post your attempt then.I will see if you or I might have made mistakes.

Comment: Reflect and shift the part of the circuit which you have circled, in the y-axis and then add a resistance in the wire with zero resistance. You will get a balanced Wheatstone bridge. Hence no current will flow through that part and you will get 2R in parallel with 2R.

Comment: @MrAP yeah if the bottom wire also had a resistance R then it becomes a different question if Wheatstone bridge and then the equivalent resistance comes out to be R

Answer (score 7):

If you label the resistors clockwise, you will get R1 and R2 parallel to each other; the R3 and R4 will be parallel to each other. Both pairs are in series between A and B.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEm2U6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why have you made R1 and R2 share a common point?Similar for R3 and R4.

Comment: When confused by equivalent resistances, always redraw. Nicely visualized!

Comment: @MrAP because they are all connected (with wires) to C.

Comment: If you still do not see how this circuit was re-drawn, try coloring the wires that belong to the nodes. Thus, in the circuit above, you can use three colors.

Comment: What will be the equivalent resistance if a resistor of resistance R is added to the bottom wire. I am getting R. I applied the Wheatstone bridge principle.

Comment: Just draw the new circuit. I do not know how Wheatstone bridge applies there. I know there are triangle-to-star resistance network conversions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to consider this is by inserting a test voltage source and finding the resulting current. From there, Ohm's Law can be used to find the equivalent resistance.  This is the fundamental method for finding the equivalent resistance from which series and parallel are derived. If you are confused whether something is in series or parallel, I recommend you use this method and analyze the result.

Take a look at the schematic below which inserts a 1V test source into the schematic you gave.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTe0Cs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using Node-Voltage method, the equation at node A will be:
$$
\frac{1V}{2R} + \frac{1V}{2R} - I_1 = 0
$$

1V is the voltage between node A and B. The first term is the current flowing from one of the loops between node A and B. It is a resistance of 2R because regardless of the path you take, you encounter two resistances to get to node B. The second term the current flowing from the other loop between node A and B. The third term is the current flowing through the test source. It is a negative current because I treat each current as flowing outwards from node A.

Solving for I1 gives R as the current. With a voltage source of 1V, this yields a resistance of R.

This gives the same result as a parallel configuration, so in essence the resistors are in parallel. One way to think of it is that starting at node A, the current **must** go through two resistors to get to node B. The shorted wire provides another path to get to node B but the end result is that the resistors are in parallel.

**Note:** If one of the resistors connected to node B were replaced with a larger/smaller value than R, the result will be different from a parallel configuration and it will be like the resistors are not in parallel.

Comment: So are they in parallel?

Comment: Sorry, I got carried away in equivalent resistance that I forgot to actually answer the question. They are in parallel. I will update my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Draw an extended line through AB and fold the circuit, using this line as axis.